# Integration of c-xunit tests with pytest

Tags: c, unit-testing, pytest

I have a project written in C- that is using pytest wrapper to do functional testing: tests are compiled into C-program and run by pytest. Pytest sets up  the environment, runs the program and then interprets the results returned by the program.

I would like to add a proper xunit tests and integrate them into overall pytest environment. It is uncomplicated but I cannot use c++, hence I cannot use gtest, tests should be compiled into a simple executable, hence I cannot use frameworks like atf that run each test case in a separate process.

I do not need fancy reporters and I am considering to write the framework myself, but I strongly prefer not to reinvent the wheel. So, is there anything useful I can use?

Comment: It is possible to use gtest for testing C code. If you want to mock C functions you can write (or if possible generate) C wrappers for the C++ mock functions. If you have a function `a()` that calls `b()` and you want to mock `b()` for testing `a()`, you will have difficulties adding tests for the real function `b()` to the same executable. There are test frameworks for C, e.g. http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I cannot link c++ code to the project.

Comment: You should add all clarification to the question. I just noticed that the URL in my previous comment is a link to one of the tools only, you should also check the "HOME" or "TOOLS" links on this site. I'm not associated with this project or the organization behind it. I successfully tested this framework for a pure C project at work and would have chosen it, but it was decided to use gtest/gmock as this was already in use and known in other teams of the company. There are other tools for testing C code, e.g. https://sourceforge.net/projects/embunit/, http://aceunit.sourceforge.net/...